# Integrating a function with $\mathrm dx$ as an exponent

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am a high school student learning calculus. I encountered this what seems to be a challange problem:$$\int(x^{\mathrm dx}-1)$$We have learned some integrating techniques, but we still didn’t learn integration by parts. All the previous problems I encountered didn’t have $\mathrm dx$ as an exponent, so I really don’t know where to start.

Update:
Here's how my teacher approached the question

-Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $dx$ then find the integral

$$
\int \frac{\left(x^{d x}-1\right) d x}{d x}
$$

Comment: We don't have $dx$ as an exponent because that doesn't really make sense, especially for a high school context. Are you sure that's how the question is printed?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: If you choose $dx$ to be infinitesimally small, then $x^{dx} \approx 1$, so the integral $\approx x+c$

Comment: We usually write $dx=x'=1$ when taking derivative, so $dx=x'=1$, so we may let $x^{dx}=x'=1$ and integrand can be $(x^1-1)$ and integral can be $\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+c$.

Comment: It's a challenge problem, all right, the challenge being how to make any sense out of it. I suggest you take it back to whomever gave it to you and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 9):

This is more a recreational quiz than a real question, as the notation is unorthodoxical and in principle meaningless.

Considering the Taylor development of the exponential,

$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

we can expand symbolically

$$\int (x^{dx}-1)=\int (e^{\ln x\,dx}-1)=\int(\ln x\,dx+\frac12\ln^2 x\,dx^2+\frac1{3!}\ln^2 x\,dx^3+\cdots).$$

Then as the $dx^k$ represent higher degree infinitesimals, they could be neglected and

$$\int (x^{dx}-1)=\int\ln x\,dx.$$

Anyway, this statement is not rigourous and it is not true that these terms can just be neglected. An expression like $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,dx^2$ is still undefined.

Comment: The only correct answer that this notation does not really make sense (+1)

Answer (score 3):

When $dx$ is a true infinitesimal (e.g. interpreted as an infinitesimal in [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)) , it is possible to make sense out of the "integral". 
However, I have strong doubt that this is the intended interpretation.

Since the Riemann like sum
$$S(\Delta x) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum x^{\Delta x} - 1$$
is defined for  finite $\Delta x > 0$. By transfer principle of hyperreals, the function $S(dx)$ is defined for all infinitesimal $dx > 0$. 
Like the ordinary construction of integral in the framework of hyperreals, if the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) of $S(dx)$ is a real number independent of choice of $dx$, we can use it as a definition of the "integral" $\int x^{dx} - 1$.

Translate this back to standard analysis, we can interpret the "integral" as a limit of Riemann like sum
$$\int_a^b x^{dx} - 1 = \lim_{\delta(P) \to 0 } \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^*)^{\Delta x_i} - 1$$

where $P$ stands for any [tagged partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval#Tagged_partitions) of $[a,b]$:

$$a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b\quad\text{ and }\quad  x_k^* \in [ x_{k-1}, x_k ]\quad\text{ for } 1 \le k \le n$$
and $\delta(P) = \max_k \{ x_k - x_{k-1} : 1 \le k \le n \}$ is the mesh of the partition.

If I'm not mistaken, the indefinte "integral" evaluates to
$$\int x^{dx} - 1 \stackrel{?}{=} \int \log x dx = x\log x - x + \text{constant}$$

For more details about this sort of approach to calculus through infinitesimals, Jerome Keisler's classic
[Elementary Calculus - an infinitesimal approarch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K2PC8SY) will be an excellent reference.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This is NOT a rigorous treatment)

We have
$$lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x - 1}{x} = \ln(a)$$
$$\implies (a^x - 1) \approx x \ln(a)$$
for very small $x$.

**Note**: what we want to basically show is, for very small $\Delta x$:
$$x^{\Delta x} - 1 \approx ln(x) {\Delta x}$$
For example:
$$(10000^{0.001} - 1) - (\ln(10000)*0.001) = 0.0000425$$
$$(0.5^{0.001} - 1) - (\ln(0.5)*0.001) = 0.00000024$$

Hence
$$\int(x^{dx} - 1) \approx \int \ln(x) dx = \boxed{ x\ln(x) - x + C}$$

where $C$ is a constant.