# What is $\int x^{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Sometimes I come across integrals like this $$\int x^{dx}$$ on the internet. What does this mean? Also, what is the standard nomenclature?

Edit- Apparently, this is called a 'geometric integral', see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).

Comment: Could you give a link where you saw this?

Comment: Can you link to an example where you've found this? It looks to me like a typo.

Comment: No, this is meaningless.

Comment: @saulspatz, as usual, great mind think alike!

Comment: @BarryCipra [Flammable maths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqmIGr68RCo)

Comment: I just learned this recently!  There are videos on YouTube explaining it.

Comment: @robert What does these 'integrals' mean?

Comment: Here is a similar question:[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201425/integrating-a-function-with-mathrm-dx-as-an-exponent)

Comment: Take a look at this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral.

Comment: It is essentially the same as the normal integral, but with some exponentiation.

Comment: Another discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201425/integrating-a-function-with-mathrm-dx-as-an-exponent?noredirect=1